# How to conditionally add flags to shell scripts?

Tags: bash, scripting

I want to run a command inside my bash script with or without a `-v` flag depending on if the environment variable $VERBOSE is defined. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/local/bin/mongo-connector \
  -m $MONGO_HOST \
  -t $NEO_URI \
  [if $VERBOSE then -v ] \
  -stdout
```

Answer (score 46):

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/local/bin/mongo-connector \
  -m "$MONGO_HOST" \
  -t "$NEO_URI" \
  ${VERBOSE:+-v} \
  -stdout
```

If VERBOSE is set and non-empty, then `${VERBOSE:+-v}` evaluates to `-v`.  If VERBOSE is unset or empty, it evaluates to the empty string.  Note that this is an instance where you must avoid using double quotes.  If you write: `cmd "${VERBOSE:+-v}"` rather than `cmd ${VERBOSE+:v}`, the behavior is semantically different when VERBOSE is empty or unset.  In the former case, `cmd` is called with one argument (the empty string), while in the latter case `cmd` is called with zero arguments.

To test if VERBOSE is set to a particular string, you can do things like:

```
/usr/local/bin/mongo-connector \
  -m "$MONGO_HOST" \
  -t "$NEO_URI" \
  $(case ${VERBOSE} in (v1) printf -- '-v foo';; (v2) printf -- '-v bar';; esac )\
  -stdout
```

but it seems cleaner to write that as

```
case "${VERBOSE}" in
v1) varg=foo;;
v2) varg=bar;;
*)  unset varg;;
esac
/usr/local/bin/mongo-connector -m "$MONGO_HOST" -t "$NEO_URI" \
      ${varg+-v "$varg"} -stdout
```

Again, note the use of double quotes here.  You want them around `$varg` to ensure that only one string is passed, and you do not want `"${varg+-v "$varg"}"` because you want to ensure that you do not pass an empty string.  Also, since the case statement explicitly unsets `varg`, we can now omit the `:`.

Comment: yes, but how to check if $VERBOSE is set to a specific value? thanks

Comment: If you want to check a specific value, you'll need to write some explicit comparisons.  eg, a `case` statement.  There's no simple shortcut.

Comment: A very simple example of might be:  [[ ${VERBOSE/A SPECIFIC VALUE/YES} == YES ]] && { stuff for when VERBOSE is “A SPECIFIC VALUE”; }

Answer (score 42):

For readability, consider using an array to store the arguments.

```
args=(
  -m "$MONGO_HOST"
  -t "$NEO_URI"
  -stdout
)
if [[ -v VERBOSE ]]; then
    args+=(-v)
fi
/usr/local/bin/mongo-connector "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: Although it may not be an issue, this changes the order of the arguments.

Comment: True; you can leave `-stdout` of the original assignment, then add `args+=(-stdout)` after the `if` statement to address that.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```sh
composer dump-autoload $([ "$env" = "production" ] && printf '--classmap-authoritative')
```

Comment: Needed to use `printf -- -n` when inserting `-n` flag.

Answer (score 1):

There are already good answers here. One alternative not yet mentioned is redefining your command string diretctly.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

CMD=/usr/local/bin/mongo-connector

[[ "$VERBOSE" ]] && CMD="$CMD --verbose"

$CMD \
  -m "$MONGO_HOST" \
  -t "$NEO_URI" \
  -stdout
```

Comment: You do know that `[[ -n "$VERBOSE" ]]` or even `[[ "$VERSBOSE" ]]` is the same as your test that negates the `-z` rigth?