# How to conditionally add flag in Fishshell

Tags: fish

I want to set a flag when `$DEBUG[1]` is set:

In bash this would be the way [`${DEBUG:+-v}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42985611/how-to-conditionally-add-flags-to-shell-scripts), how to do it in Fishshell?

For example:

```sh
yarn config (not set -q DEBUG[1] && echo "-s") delete proxy
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If you're in a code block (function/begin-end) you can use a variable with [Brace Expansion](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#expand-brace):</strike>

```sh
set -q DEBUG[1] && set -l silent "-s"
yarn config $silent delete proxy
```

edit: [faho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3150338/faho) [added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59378703/how-to-conditionally-add-flag-in-fishshell/59378864?noredirect=1#comment104949913_59378864) that it works also without brace expansion

Comment: That brace expansion adds nothing. Just `yarn config $silent delete proxy` will do the exact same thing.

Comment: How to do it in one line?

Comment: Not sure why you want a one-liner since it decreases readability but this works: `yarn config (set -q DEBUG[1]; and echo -- -s) delete proxy`. Notice the `echo -- -s` because `-s` is a valid flag for `echo`.