# Getting unknown long flag error while passing flags optionally

Tags: scripting, zsh

I'm trying to add the flag optionally based on condition and environment variables. I've taken reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42985611/how-to-conditionally-add-flags-to-shell-scripts).
I've executed commands like this -

```
export DOWN_MIGRATE=true
export NO_OF_DOWN_MIGRATIONS="2"
./scripts abc.sh ${DOWN_MIGRATE:+--migrate-only down $NO_OF_DOWN_MIGRATIONS}
```

but it is throwing the following error:

```
main: error: unknown long flag '--migrate-only down 2'
exit status 1
```

The following command works fine:

```
./scripts abc.sh --migrate-only down 2
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Have you changed `IFS`? Also, are you sure this is running under bash, and not zsh?

Comment: @Gordon I’ve not changed IFS but I’m using zsh

Comment: In that case, the bash tag is not appropriate; I'll change it to zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zsh has a number of significant differences from most Bourne-ish shells. You're running into one of the biggest differences: by default it doesn't split the result of variable expansions into separate "words". In this case, that means that the expansion of `${DOWN_MIGRATE:+--migrate-only down $NO_OF_DOWN_MIGRATIONS}` is passed as a single long argument, rather than being split into three words ("`--migrate-only`", "`down`", and "`2`"). The single long argument confuses the script.

You can tell zsh that you want word-splitting done by adding [the `=` modifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) to the expansion:

```
./scripts abc.sh ${=DOWN_MIGRATE:+--migrate-only down $NO_OF_DOWN_MIGRATIONS}
```

Note that if `$NO_OF_DOWN_MIGRATIONS` expanded to multiple words, that'd also be split. If you want to avoid that possibility (but keep the splitting of "`--migrate-only`" and "`down`"), you can double-quote just that part:

```
./scripts abc.sh ${=DOWN_MIGRATE:+--migrate-only down "$NO_OF_DOWN_MIGRATIONS"}
```

Anytime you take code samples intended for bash or other POSIX shells and put them in a zsh script, you need to be aware that zsh may do things differently from what the code assumes.